# Java: reading all keys from lmdb JNI into array

Tags: java, arrays, lmdb

I want to read all the keys from lmdb into a list, using `bufferCursor`, but I am getting index out of bound error.

```
String[] keys=new String[keyCount]; //keyCount gives no. of keys in lmdb tree
int count=0;
cursor.first(); //to move to first position
while(cursor.next){
    keys[count]= cursor.keyUtf8(0).getString().toString(); //getting error in this line it's working for reading values.
    count++l
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `keyCount` is to low of a number, or maybe even zero.

If you don't know how many key are going to be in an array, initialize the `String[]` array with a number larger than zero. Then, as you add more items, make sure `keys.length()` is large enough to accept a new item. If not, use `Arrays.copyOf()` to increase its size. Check out the Javadoc for the function [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int))

Also, you can use a higher level array, like `ArrayList`. This will ensure you never add more items than the array can handle, by performing the `copyOf()` method internally automatically.

Such as:

```
ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(keyCount); //keyCount gives no. of keys in lmdb tree
int count=0;
cursor.first(); //to move to first position

while(cursor.next){
   keys.add(cursor.keyUtf8(0).getString().toString()); //getting error in this line it's working for reading values.
   count++l
}
```

Comment: It's an internal error on lmdb library on cursor, i am able to read values in same way correctly